# Как при абсолютном позиционировании зафиксировать картинку, чтобы она никуда не уезжала?

Tags: css3, html5

Как при абсолютном позиционировании зафиксировать картинку(стрелку), чтобы она никуда не уезжала?

```css
.bg2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/scNnI.png);
  position: relative
}

.bg2:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbETp.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: 42.1%;
  transform: translateX(16%);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 206px;
  height: 114px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg2'></div>
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91575/discussion-between-alex-and-user312259).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.bg2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/scNnI.png);
  position: relative;
  height: 1048px;
}

.bg2:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbETp.png);
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 99px);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 198px;
  height: 114px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg2'></div>
```

P.S.: в данном ответе показано позиционирование по центру, т.к. судя по [чату](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91575/discussion-between-alex-and-user312259), Вам нужна была такая позиция. Если все же нужен сдвиг `transform: translateX(16%);`, то просто добавьте эту строчку в код.